# More precise way of solving inequality

Tags: functions, inequality

I need to solve this function:
$$
\lvert x^2-1\rvert\ge 2x-2\\
$$

I solved this equation:

For $x<0$, the solution is non existing, here I got negative root, when I tried to solve quadratic function and for $x\ge 0$ I got points $x_1=-1$ and $x_2=3$.

My question is:

How do I set the solution of equation. Is there any procedure, with wich I can determine is equation valid for $[-1,3]$ or $[-\infty, -1]\lor [3, +\infty]$.

I know that I can just set the numbers and see the result, but I just want to now is there any other different way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: That's an inequality, not a function.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote the title very fast, so I got a little bit confuesd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $\displaystyle |x|=\begin{cases} x &\mbox{if }  x\ge0 \\-x  & \mbox{if } x<0 \end{cases} $

If $x^2-1\ge0\iff x\ge1$ or $x\le-1,$

we get $$x^2-1\ge2x-2\iff x^2-2x+1\ge0\iff (x-1)^2\ge0$$ which is true

If $x^2<1\iff -1<x<1\  \ \  \  (1),$

we get $$-(x^2-1)>2x-2\iff x^2+2x-3<0$$

$$\iff (x+3)(x-1)<0\iff -3<x<1\  \ \ \ (2)$$

Now using $(1),(2)-1<x<1$

So, $x$ can assume any real value

Comment: Another way:

As $\displaystyle|x^2-1|\ge0, |x^2-1|\ge 2x-2$ if $2x-2\le0\iff x\le1$

If $\displaystyle x>1, x^2>1\implies |x^2-1|=x^2-1$ we can solve as in the answer

Comment: I dont understand this part of explenation, can you please clarify it. "But as −1<x<1,−1<x<1". Thanks.

Comment: @depecheSoul, edited the answer, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3):

Before trying an “automated” method, it's better to have a close look at the problem.

You can first of all observe that if $2x-2<0$, then the inequality obviously holds, because $|x^2-1|\ge0$. So all values $x<1$ will satisfy the inequality.

Now suppose $x\ge 1$. In this case also $x^2\ge1$, so we can write the inequality as
$$
x^2-1\ge 2x-2
$$
which becomes
$$
x^2-2x+1\ge0
$$
or
$$
(x-1)^2\ge0
$$
which is surely true for all $x$, in particular for $x\ge 1$.

Conclusion: the inequality holds for all real $x$.

---

The "automated" method has been treated in other answers; to summarize it, you can divide the inequality into two and you'll put together the solution sets at the end
$$
\begin{cases}
x^2-1\ge0\\
x^2-1\ge 2x-2
\end{cases}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\begin{cases}
x^2-1<0\\
1-x^2\ge 2x-2
\end{cases}
$$
Simple algebraic manipulation transforms them into
$$
\begin{cases}
x\le -1 \text{ or }x\ge1\\
(x-1)^2\ge0
\end{cases}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\begin{cases}
-1<x<1\\
x^2+2x-3\le0
\end{cases}
$$
and, going on,
$$
x\le -1\text{ or }x\ge 1
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\begin{cases}
-1<x<1\\
-3\le x\le 1
\end{cases}
$$
whence the same conclusion as before. (Note: the brace is another way of saying “and”.)

Comment: One question: you are connecting functions with logical operator "OR", so when for example $x^2−1≥2x−2$ is true, the and $1−x^2≥2x−2$ is false, then the function $x^2−1≥2x−2$ is valid. Thanks

Comment: @depecheSoul No, I don't mean that. What's true is that, for example, the original inequation is equivalent to the following “or“ assertion. This means that any solution for one system is a solution of the original inequality (and conversely).

Answer (score 2):

You have two cases :

Case 1 : When $x^2-1\ge0$, you have $x^2-1\ge 2x-2.$

Case 2 : When $x^2-1\lt0$, you have $-(x^2-1)\ge 2x-2.$

The answer is $$"x^2-1\ge0\ \text{and}\ x^2-1\ge 2x-2"\ \text{or}\ "x^2-1\lt0\ \text{and}\ -(x^2-1)\ge 2x-2."$$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}|x|<1\implies x^2-1<0\implies |x^2-1|=1-x^2\\
|x|\ge 1\implies x^2-1\ge 0\implies |x^2-1|=x^2-1\end{align*}$$

So, for example, for  $\;x=-1\;$ you get

$$|(-1)^2-1|\ge 2(-1)-2\iff2\ge-4\;\color{green}{\checkmark}$$

Comment: I guess you picked up the `\checkmark` from my question? :p

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you're talking about, @Adobe ...

Answer (score 0):

Clearly $x=1$ is a solution.  Dividing by $|x-1|$ yields to
$$|x+1|\leq2\frac{x-1}{|x-1|},$$
which is obviously true both for $x<1$ and $x>1$.